# Display split button option

Tags: extjs

I have created a split button in with options. I need the value of the option that I click from the click button to be displayed next to the button. I tried the following code that I wrote, but it doesnt display the option. suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
text: 'Options',
    handler: function() {
    alert("The button was clicked");
},
menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
    items: [
        {text: 'Item 1', handler: function({
           Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
                        value: 'Item 1'}
                    )}
                },
        {text: 'Item 2', handler: function(){ {
           Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
                        value: 'Item 2'}
                    )}
                }
          ]
     })
});
```

Comment: You're not rendering the field anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you dont render your display fields anywhere, just create (JS) object (as Evan said).

And, second, I doubt you have to create display field each time you select option. Just add single display field to your app and update its value.

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sc0).

Answer (score 0):

try this fiddle may give you some idea [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1s6s)

The way you are trying is wrong you cannot directly create **Ext.form.DisplayField** without container for that

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. There's no need for a container, the field just needs to be rendered.

Comment: thanks for correcting me,may be i am wrong let me check again